# How to set default selected option value taken from server side (php) in select drop down using angularjs

Tags: php, json, angularjs

In the code below select drop down working fine, but now I need to set the default option of the select from the response options of server side.
That matching data is also retrieved from server side (PHP).  What's wrong with my code? Is there a correct way in angularjs or any is there any other option available?
I referred more than stack overflow's.  but in all that issues only static values are solved.not from server side..
 Thanks advance

```
 **My HTML**    
<select ng-model="frameedit.brand_name" ng-options="brand.id as brand.brand_name for brand in frame_product_options.brand_type">
</select>
```

**My Controller**

```
$scope.frame_product_options_get=function(){  
    $http.post("ajax/frame_product_select_data.php").
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {  
            $scope.frame_product_options=data;  
            $scope.frameedit.brand_name=data.brand_type_match[0]; //just try to assign.but it's not work..
        });  
}
```

**my json console data from server side(PHP)**

```
  Overall Data:  

    brand_type[Object { id="1", brand_name="RAY-BAN"}, Object { id="2", brand_name="Bolle"}, Object { id="3", brand_name="vogue-brand"}]

want to match with the below data:  

brand_type_match[Object { id="2", brand_name="Bolle"}]
```

Comment: Can you please do a `console.log(data)` in the `success` function, and copy/paste the result here?

Comment: brand_type[Object { id="1", brand_name="RAY-BAN"}, Object { id="2", brand_name="Bolle"}, Object { id="3", brand_name="vogue-brand"}, 3 more...]
0
Object { id="1", brand_name="RAY-BAN"}
brand_name
 
 "RAY-BAN"
id
 
 "1"
1
Object { id="2", brand_name="Bolle"}
brand_name
 
 "Bolle"
id
 
 "2"
2
 
Object { id="3", brand_name="vogue-brand"}
brand_name
 
 "vogue-brand"
id
 
 "3"
3
 
Object { id="4", brand_name="police"}
brand_name
 
 "police"
id
 
 "4"
4
Object { id="5", brand_name="Esprit"}
brand_name
 
 "Esprit"
id
 
 "5"
5
Object { id="12", brand_name="carrera"}
brand_name
 
 "carrera"
id
 
 "12"

Comment: brand_type_match
 
 Object { id="2", brand_name="Bolle"}
brand_name
 
 "Bolle"
id
 
 "2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$scope.frameedit.brand_name = data.brand_type_match[0].id;
```

since the `select` part of `ng-options` is `brand.id` which is bound to `ng-model`, so setting that default value from controller must be compatible with the configuration on the view.

Comment: TypeError: data.brand_type_match[0] is undefined
 

$scope.frameedit.id =data.brand_type_match[0].id

Comment: i got the select response from server side while click each edit button.then it throw above error

Comment: @UdayaRavi Does brand_type_match exist in response and is it object or array?

Comment: sorry bro.i made a mistake..it's a object.not a array.i got it..data.brand_type_match.id;

Comment: @UdayaRavi Never mind, we are all trying to code here ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `select as label for value in array` syntax for the `ng-options` directive.

The main point here is that "select" should match the expression provided for `ng-model`.

In your `ng-model` you have provided the "brand name" but your `select` is the "brand id".

Either use the `select` as the brand name or change your `ng-model` to use brand id instead. That is use either -

```
<select ng-model="frameedit.brand_name" ng-options="brand.brand_name
    as brand.brand_name for brand in frame_product_options.brand_type">
</select>
```

OR

```
<select ng-model="frameedit.id" ng-options="brand.id
    as brand.brand_name for brand in frame_product_options.brand_type">
</select>
```

Note that the former requires that the `select`, that is the "brand_name" parameter to be unique.

Comment: i have tried second one.but it not working.but i didn't throw any error